# How to reuse cross_validation_fold_assignment() with GBM in H2o library with Python

Tags: python, h2o, gbm

I run my model with H2o library.
I run with 5 folds cross-validation.

```
model = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(
                        balance_classes=True, 
                        nfolds=5,
                        keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment=True,
                        seed=1234)
model.train(x=predictors,y=response,training_frame=data)
print('rmse: ',model.rmse(xval=True))
print('R2: ',model.r2(xval=True))
data_nfolds = model.cross_validation_fold_assignment()
```

I got the cross-validation fold assignment.
I try to reuse it for a new model with other parameters such as ntrees or stopping_rounds, but I did not find it in the documents.

> https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment.html

Comment: If you use the same training set, the same number of folds and same seed, the folds will be identical in any H2O supervised algorithm, so you don't actually need to save & re-use them if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

```
nfolds_index = h2o.import_file('myfile_index.csv')
nfolds_index.set_names(["fold_numbers"])
data = data.cbind(nfolds_index)
model2 = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator( seed=1234)
model2.train(x=predictors,y=response,training_frame=data, fold_column="fold_numbers")
print('rmse: ',model2.rmse(xval=True))
print('R2: ',model2.r2(xval=True))
```